# Grails UnexpectedRollbackException occurred: Not Sure Why

Tags: exception, grails, transactions

I have the following code:

```
class ServiceA {

   def save(Object object) {
      if (somethingBadComesBack) {
         throw new CustomRuntimeException(data)
      }
   }
}

class ServiceB {

   def serviceA

   def save(Object object) {
      try {
         serviceA.save(object)
         // do more stuff if good to go
      } catch(CustomRuntimeException e) {
        // populate some objects with errors based on exception
      }
   }
}

class ServiceC {

    def serviceB

    def process(Object object) {
       serviceB.save(object)
       if (object.hasErrors() {
          // do some stuff
       }else{
         // do some stuff
       }

       def info = someMethod(object)
       return info
    }
}

class SomeController {

   def serviceC

   def process() {

     def object = .....
     serviceC.save(object) // UnexpectedRollbackException is thrown here

   }
}
```

When `ServiceA.save()` is called and an exception occurs, `ServiceC.save()` is throwing an `UnexpectedRollbackException` when it tries to return.

I did the following:

```
try {
   serviceC.process(object)
}catch(UnexpectedRollbackException e) {
   println e.getMostSpecificCause()
}
```

and I am getting:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

I'm not sure where to start looking for how to fix this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using a runtime exception to roll back the transaction, but that's cheating - it's taking advantage of a side effect. Runtime exceptions roll back transactions automatically since you don't need to catch them so it's assumed that if one is thrown, it wasn't expected and the default behavior is to roll back. You can configure methods to not roll back for specific expected runtime exceptions, but this is somewhat rare. Checked exceptions don't roll back exceptions because in Java they must be caught or declared in the `throws`, so you have to have either explicitly thrown it or ducked it; either way you had a chance to try again.

The correct way to intentionally roll back a transaction is to call `setRollbackOnly()` on the current `TransactionStatus` but this isn't directly accessible in a service method (it is in a `withTransaction` block since it's the argument to the closure). But it's easy to get to: import `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport` and call `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()`. This will required that you rework your code since there won't be an exception to catch, so you'll need to check that it was rolled back with `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isRollbackOnly()`.

I'm not sure if it's a Grails issue or standard behavior, but when I was debugging this there were 3 commit calls with 3 different `TransactionStatus` instances. Only the first had the rollback flag set, but the second was aware of the first and was ok. The third one was considered a new transaction and was the one that triggered the same exception that you were seeing. So to work around this I added this to the 2nd and 3rd service methods:

```
def status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()
if (!status.isRollbackOnly()) status.setRollbackOnly()
```

to chain the rollback flag. That worked and I didn't get the `UnexpectedRollbackException`.

It might be easier to combine this with a checked exception. It's still overly expensive since it will fill in the stacktrace unnecessarily, but if you call `setRollbackOnly()` and throw a checked exception, you will be able to use the same general workflow you have now.

Comment: Thanks Burt.  Going to play around with this approach and see what I can get one.  I'll report back...

Comment: Grails 2.3.7 will include a feature for handling this situation by default: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11145

Comment: @FlareCoder - Thank you for sharing this!! I have just upgraded from grails 2.3.6 to 2.3.7 and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: Please fix your answer like this: if (status.isRollbackOnly()) => if (!status.isRollbackOnly())

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [default transactionality of services](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html) is biting you, and the unchecked exception thrown in Service A is dooming the transaction to rollback only, even once caught.

The above docs say the txn propagation level is [`PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#PROPAGATION_REQUIRED), which should mean the same transaction is shared from your service C on up to A, if my memory serves me.  Can you have Service A's `save` method throw a checked exception instead of RuntimeException, to avoid the auto-rollback from the latter?  Or disable transactions on your services, if that's an option for you?